# VisualBasic.net Adding Mysql database check

Tags: database

Hello good people of stack overflow i am in dire need of some and little bit of help so i been looking at this program done in vb.net here link http://www.planet-source-code.com/vb/scripts/ShowCode.asp?txtCodeId=8869&lngWId=10
it is made to stop people from opening any app or webpage with any of words in here a pic

https://i.stack.imgur.com/lA1cQ.jpg

i mark some stuff out so people wont get fended here put with programs name you can guess what they were ok so what i am asking is how would i make this work with mysql data base could you help me i got database up on server but how do i make program check the database for any word that are in TextBox3.Text.Contains so it just check the database so i can get rid of this list as i remaking what programs for

p.s if my spelling wrong i am so sorry edit as you wish or just tell me thanks people of stack

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Load the .sln into Visual Studio
2. Search the code for these words: File and Stream
3. Replace the file I/O with MySQL functionality.  There are many places on the Internet that will tell you how to do this.  For example: [Connecting-to-MySQL-databases-using-VB-NET](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/493133/Connecting-to-MySQL-databases-using-VB-NET)

Comment: thank you for your help i will have look in too this see what i can make of it

Comment: this seem very dumb of me but could you help me answer this one

If TextBox3.Text.Contains("here") Then

were here is could i put mysql query to check whole database for everything that in textbox3

Comment: I will be glad to help.  Please choose my answer as the correct one, enter your question as a new question, and provide the link as a comment.

Comment: Did you figure it out, or did you add a new question?

Comment: Right now no I've stop due not know how to do it so look at making it all my self in java